# Function that returns a string at contrary

Tags: php, html, css

I have to do a function that returns a string at contrary to another variable. I have a problem.

```
<?php 
$parolaAlContrario=""; 
function ribaltaStringa($nome){ 
    $lenght=strlen($nome); 
    for($i=0;$i<$lenght+4;$i++){ 
        $parolaAlContrario[$i]=$nome[$lenght-1]; 
        $lenght=$lenght-1; 
    } 
    echo implode($parolaAlContrario); 
} 
ribaltaStringa("marco"); ?>
```

This code returns 'ocram'. I don't understand why if I put `implode($parolaAlContrario)` outside the function the result is the variable `$parolaAlContrario` empty. Why?

Comment: You are just trying to reverse the string?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Don't go there ;-) I assume they are not allowed to use built-in functions.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I was just asking for clarification :)

Comment: I am trying to reverse a string but not in the same variable but in another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of your variable is *outside* of your function. You need to assign the variable to whatever the result is from the function.

You should make your function *return* the variable, and assign it when complete.

```
function ribaltaStringa($nome)
{
    $lenght = strlen($nome);
    $parolaAlContrario = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $lenght + 4; $i++) {
        $parolaAlContrario[$i] = $nome[$lenght - 1];
        $lenght = $lenght - 1;
    }
    return implode($parolaAlContrario);
}
```

Notice, instead of echoing the variable, I *return* the variable. This allows us to assign the result to your variable once the function is finished.

I've also defined the variable `$parolaAlContrario` inside the function right outside the loop, this will allow you to return the value.

When you call the function, you should assign the variable again.

```
$parolaAlContrario = ribaltaStringa("marco");
```

Likewise, you could make a completely new variable with the word reversed by just changing the name of the variable during declaration; E.G:

```
$newVariable = ribaltaStringa("marco");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.I have a question:how you can return $parolaAlContrario if you haven't the variable defined?

Comment: @user9318237 The variable is defined inside the for loop, but it should probably be defined outside of it too before you start adding letters to it inside the loop. One second, I will add that.

Comment: I have tried to run the code but it give nothing.Excuse me but i'm not understanding:(

Comment: @user9318237 As you can see [at this link](https://eval.in/950278), the code does work. It's probably not giving you any response because you are not echoing the result after it is set. The function will not automatically output the variable, it will only store it - then you can use the variable as you wish afterwards.

Comment: What I don't understand is why I have to assign to the variable parolaAlContrario the function if I have the variable ready at the internal of the function...

Comment: @user9318237 Because of _scope_. The function can't see that the variable is set outside of itself. Functions outside of the variable cannot be seen or interacted with at all unless used as a global or passed to the variable in PHP. Please read the link that I attached to the word "scope" in my answer in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it simple if you can make it complicated? You don't need to write your own function for that. Just use PHP's built-in function [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) which reverses a string and you can save it to a new variable if you want:

```
$parolaAlContrario = strrev('marco');
```

Try it out:
https://3v4l.org/RmdE1